# Is it ok to post questions from an agnostic point of view which question religious faith?

Tags: discussion

I've read the about and FAQ pages and they say nothing about atheists or agnostics.
I'm an agnostic and wonder if it's ok to make questions that *question* religious faith, facts, logic, etc. all made with a profound respect with the objective of learning more than arguing.

I don't want to upset anyone.

Answer (score 8):

This is my opinion, not that of the moderators, but based on what I've seen...

Plenty of atheists and agnostics have posted on the site.  Several of them still do, and I believe that one or more of the moderators would fit the description.  Questions from agnostics and atheists are welcome, *so long as they fall within the guidelines of the FAQ*.

The following are the recommendations I'd personally make to avoid having a flurry of down-votes and having your questions closed:

- First, ensure the question hasn't already been asked.

  - Most of the atheistic questions that have been closed recently have been due to being previously asked, not necessarily because anyone considered them offensive.
- Second, ensure that you're phrasing it as an honest question, and not a thinly veiled attack.

  - "Why do people believe that Jesus was a real person when there's no evidence for it" would get flagged.
  - "What is the historical, extra-Biblical historical evidence for the existence of Jesus" would likely stand (except that it's a duplicate of a previously asked question)
- Follow all of the guidelines of the FAQ.  Don't ask questions that can have no right answer, or questions that can have no supportable answer.
- Be polite.
- Accept answers to your questions.

  - Be prepared to accept that fact that you might not always get answers you *agree* with.  You, *like all of us*, come with bias and a predisposition to interpret evidence a certain way.
  - Accepting answers that you agree are reasonable arguments, even if you don't agree with the conclusion and commenting as to why you're accepting an answer you don't believe show that, in good faith, you're open to ideas.  In order to keep the questions intellectually honest, **simply don't ask questions to which you know you will never accept any "Christian" answer.**   Those are not questions, they're jabs, and get down-voted and closed quickly.

In short, be polite, be fair, be respectful, and play by the rules.  If yo do so, you'll likely be treated the same in turn.

Comment: There's no actual compulsion to accept answers. It's a good idea, for many reasons, but it's not required, and if in your honest judgment you cannot accept any of the answers on your question, you don't need to hold your nose and pick the "least worse" one.

Comment: @TRig - I agree...As I said, it was just my opinion, and the motivation was only so you don't look like you're attacking.  To me, it seems a good way to force yourself to phrase the question in a way that's answerable is all.  Your questions, for example, usually fall well within what I'd consider good.  You're not out to attack, and hence, you do accept answers, if not all.  Others I've seen simply post rapid-fire questions that really are clearly just attacks.  You play by the rules, in other words, and keep it respectful.

Comment: David I think your "sanity check" metric about parsing questions in such a way that you will potentially be able to accept an answer is brilliant. A significant number of the problematic questions we've seen would fail that simple test.

Comment: @David. I'm definitely out to attack. I just try not to do it here. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Having read the FAQ you'll have read this:

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about **_**”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain **_** to me”, then you are probably OK.

The site is for finding out more about Christianity, not for challenging people's faith or beliefs. It's also specifically about Christianity, not about religious belief or faith in general. Finally the subject matter experts here are experts in Christianity not other fields. Obviously Christianity overlaps with every other subject under the Sun, including the sciences, history, archaeology, politics, general philosophy, etc. If your question is about one of those, as opposed to Christianity itself, this is probably not the right place for it.

I hope that helps. If in doubt feel free to ask here or in chat about whether a specific question would be a good fit for the site.